# Adding raster file name to attribute table of polygonised version of raster file using QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, raster, attribute-table, qgis-modeler

I have a polygonised output of a raster file but need to add the raster filename to the attribute table of the polygon (vector) file. I can do this manually using the command 'base_layer_name' but I have many individual raster files and therefore need to automate this process within a model.

I am using the modeler within QGIS. I have a folder containing approx. 1000 raster files that I need to create individual polygons for further vector analysis (overlap, union etc.) with other polygons. I need to insert the filename of the raster into the attribute table of the polygon so that I can maintain the identity of the source data when outputs are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Export layers(s) information to create a polygon layer of the raster extent with attributes like:

- Raster layer name
- Raster source

Then intersect this with your polygonized raster layer to add the columns to your polygonized raster:

[image]